# If IP is connectionless protocol then why does virtual packet switching is connection oriented?

Tags: tcp

We all say that IP is connection less protocol but network layer provides us with switching facility wherein we have packet switching under which, we have virtual packet switching which is connection oriented i.e resources are reserved on the way. Then why do we say IP is connection less as every packet travels in IP datagram?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533686/why-do-we-say-the-ip-protocol-in-tcp-ip-suite-is-connectionless

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that network layer has many other protocols which might use virtual ckt concept. IP uses datagram service, so it is connectionless. Because in datagram service packets go independently without any reservation of resources.